# How to concatenate two equal dataframes in pandas, differentiating between repetitions by id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

In python3 and pandas I have two dataframes with the same structure

```
df_posts_final_1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>                                           
RangeIndex: 32669 entries, 0 to 32668
Data columns (total 12 columns):
post_id        32479 non-null object
text           31632 non-null object
post_text      30826 non-null object
shared_text    3894 non-null object
time           32616 non-null object
image          24585 non-null object
likes          32669 non-null object
comments       32669 non-null object
shares         32669 non-null object
post_url       26157 non-null object
link           4343 non-null object
cpf            32669 non-null object
dtypes: object(12)
memory usage: 3.0+ MB

df_posts_final_2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>                                           
RangeIndex: 33883 entries, 0 to 33882
Data columns (total 12 columns):
post_id        33698 non-null object
text           32755 non-null object
post_text      31901 non-null object
shared_text    3986 non-null object
time           33829 non-null object
image          25570 non-null object
likes          33883 non-null object
comments       33883 non-null object
shares         33883 non-null object
post_url       27286 non-null object
link           4446 non-null object
cpf            33883 non-null object
dtypes: object(12)
memory usage: 3.1+ MB
```

I want to unite them and I could just do it like this:

```
frames = [df_posts_final_1, df_posts_final_1]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

But the "post_id" column has unique identification codes. So when there is an id "X" in df_posts_final_1 it doesn't need to appear two times in the final dataframe result

Example, if the code "FLK1989" appears in df_posts_final_1 and also in df_posts_final_2, I leave only the last record that was in df_posts_final_2

Please, does anyone know the correct strategy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code add `groupby` + `tail`

```
frames = [df_posts_final_1, df_posts_final_2]
result = pd.concat(frames).groupby('post_id').tail(1)
```

Or we do `drop_duplicates`

```
frames = [df_posts_final_2,df_posts_final_1]#order here is important 
result = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates('post_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
result = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates(subset='post_id', keep='last')
```

The `keep='last'` parameter will keep only the second one, as you want.